# I can't use default state value in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I can't use default state value in redux

Hello,
I have a function to dispatch Login action,
I want in the initial to be `false`,

but when I put this value in the render method, it's given me an error

> `can't read property 'isLogin' of undefined`

although in the reducer i add an initialState

```
let initialState = {
  isLogin: false,
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case IS_LOGIN:
      state = {
        ...state,
        isLogin: true,
      };
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
};
```

here's Store

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    count: countPlayReducer,
  }),
);
```

Action

```
export const isLoginFunc = isLogin => {
  return {
    type: IS_LOGIN,
    payload: isLogin,
  };
};
```

UI/Dispatching

```
import {isLoginFunc} from '../../redux/actions/isLoginAction';

 signIn = async data => {
   this.setState({loading: true}); // maybe here the wrong?
   API.post('/login', data)
    .then(async response => {
     let {
       data: {
         data: {
           response: {token},
         },
      },
    } = response;
    this.props.dispatch(isLoginFunc(true));
    await saveToken('id_token', token);
    this.setState({loading: false}, () =>
      this.props.navigation.navigate({
        key: 'TabHome',
        routeName: 'TabHome',
      }),
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({loading: false, error: error.response.data});
  });
```

};

```
render(){
    ...
      <Text>{this.props.user.isLogin}</Text>
    ...
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogin: state.user,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're mapping redux state using the following:

```
mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogin: state.user,
  };
};
```

But then you're trying to access `isLogin` via:

`this.props.user.isLogin`

Looks like this should be changed to:

`this.props.isLogin.isLogin`

**However** you might want to alter your mapping to the following instead:

```
mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogin: state.user.isLogin,
  };
};
```

So that you can simply use:

`this.props.isLogin`

Comment: hmm, I don't know if I'm right, please tell me if I'm wrong,, Now `state.user` that's mean we import user key reducer, and in this reducer, we want access to isLogin by `user.isLogin`?

Comment: @OliverD Good point!!  I've added an extra suggestion on how the mapping can be changed in addition to the prop access.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, but when i log `console.log(this.props.isLogin)` I got the `true` value but when i add it in `<Text>isLogin:{this.props.isLogin} // it's empty not give me a "true" value </Text>`

Comment: Should I ? How can i do it?

Comment: I mean did you also update the props mapping to the `isLogin: state.user.isLogin` suggestion in my answer?  If you could put a jsFiddle together I can have a better look at what you now have?

Comment: actually it's React Native Project, So yeah I do, It's work fine :) thank you

Comment: please, do not get upset of me :) but can you re-check SignIn Function? I got this Error  `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` when calling it

Comment: @OliverD If you're still experiencing that issue I'd suggest a separate question - alternatively look up that error message and see if you can resolve as it's a common mistake.